# В чем смысл Sphinx Engine, если он возвращает не данные, а только ID документов?

Tags: search, php, sphinx

В чем смысл **Sphinx Engine**, если он возвращает не данные, а `только ID найденных запиcей`, после чего необходимо заново *делать запрос в БД по их ID.*

Итого, количество запросов в БД от одного пользовательского запроса, в случае, если результат найден по всем индексам в *sphinx.conf*, равен количеству этих индексов.

Иначе если у меня определено **20 индексов** и по всем им было **найдено** совпадение, то необходимо выполнить **20 запросов** в разные таблицы Mysql по вернувшимся от Sphinx **ID**.
И почему Sphinx не поддерживает полную выдачу информации, кроме ID, все равно информация лежит в проиндексированных файлах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это поисковый движок, по умолчанию он возвращает ID найденых документов. Если вы прочтете документацию, то сможете легко выводить и другие поля.

На моем опыте необходимо было сделать запрос, который из нескольких таблиц собирал одну и помещался в sphinx, индексируя только несколько полей, остальные поля нужны были для показа дополнительной информации и чтобы не лазить за ними в БД.

UDP. Можно сделать так, что sphinx заменит вам БД c агрегированой информацией, не нагружая постоянно БД тяжелыми запросами.

UPD2. [Ссылочка в помощь](http://sphinxsearch.com/wiki/doku.php?id=fields_and_attributes) и [еще одна](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-2.2.5.html#attributes).

Comment: Если я правильно понял из приведенной Вами документации, чтобы Sphinx вернул столбец с именем, нужно использовать тип **sql_field_string** в составлении запроса **sql_query**

Comment: Вроде бы работает, только в результате данные от одного индекса. Почему так? Хотя ищет по всем.